# Replacing x or more dots

Tags: php, regex

I want a clean solution to replace dots in text:

Some title.... to this: Some title...

Some.... title...... to this: Some... title...

How can I replace every sequence of more than 3 dots with 3 dots?

Comment: Please specify in which language.

Comment: Did you try anything at all, or just assume someone would gladly do your work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a regular expression based search and replace[<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\.{4,}/', '...', $text);
```

The pattern says: Match four or more dots `.`, the second parameter is the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Its almost same as hakre. But more cleaner.

```
preg_replace('/\.\.\.+/', '...', $str);
```

Another repeated way (*non-regex*)

```
while(strpos($str, "....")!==false)
    $str = str_replace("....", "...", $str);
```

Comment: Note that the non-regex method will not replace 5+ dots.